# Rack cabinet - ProLiant DL360 G5 and StorageWorks fit

Tags: hp-proliant, rack, hardware

I'm about to order a rack cabinet/enclosure for our 3 HP ProLiant DL360 G5 servers and 2 StorageWork MSA units. The HP Proliant DL360 G6 is 1U each, and the StorageWork MSA Units is 2U.

The Cabinet i'm looking at is a Toten 19'' 600x800 (mm) enclosure. The dimensions of the  ProLiant DL360 G5 is

> Form Factor   Rack (1U), (1.75 in/4.45 cm); 27.75 inch depth (70.5cm)

Would the MSA and the DL360 G5 Server fit in the Toten 19'' 600x800 mm enclosure?

I got all the rails for the servers, so that is not an issue, I do not need shelves. I do know that the MSA doesn't go "as deep" as the DL360 G5 servers.

I believe it will fit, but as I can't return the enclosure, I have to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll fit yes, unless you have a lot of other bits and bobs stuck out the front or back of the servers (LR SFP/SFP+'s don't like having doors pressed against them) but yes it'll fit - that said I tend to by 1000mm deep racks myself but then I use more C7000 blades than DLs.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have nothing sticking out the ends except for the power powersupply, ethernet etc. I guess it'll work. Thanks